# how to upload a file with ajax,like what gmail does?

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I know how to POST/GET text values with ajax,

but never know how to upload files with ajax.

Can someone just give a simple demo here?

Answer (score 4):

GMail is actually using Flash for uploading files now... You could try looking into something like [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/).

Comment: I'm not familiar with flash.Isn't there a solution for doing this with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax could certainly upload files by posting a HTML form with a input type="file" in it.

Some links to get you started:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html

http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Depending on the server/server side language you could probably send some kind of progress info to the client to render as a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Ajax upload scripts](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), it has examples in Php and .Net. The basic idea behind the script is that you have to create an iFrame to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The [YUI uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/) is a flash based uploader that is designed to be very easy to integrate into javascript, with minimal knowledge of flash.

If you want a progress bar, I believe a pure javascript solution would require a server side piece to send back the current completion percentage via ajax, which would add quite a bit of complexity compared to a flash solution.